# How do you .unwrap() an element multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to use Jquery's `.unwrap()` multiple times without copying and pasting? It'd be nice if it could accept an argument or something like: `.unwrap(4)` but it doesn't. Is there a more clever solution to achieving the following:?

```js
$(".foo a").unwrap().unwrap().unwrap().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="foo">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="foo">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="foo">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is this for a project or curiosity? If it's the former and you feel you have to use unwrap that many times I would suggest maybe just cloning/destroying the element and appending it to the parent.

Comment: `$(".foo > div").replaceWith($(".foo a"))`?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) { $(".foo a").unwrap(); }`

Comment: whatever method you use should be conscious that using multiple unwraps won't perform nearly as well as a one time replacement method

Comment: @ShemSeger See post. Briefest was able to reduce to , here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could always write your own:

```
$.fn.unwrapTimes = function(times){
    var unwrapCount = times;
    return this.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        for(var i=0;i<unwrapCount;i++){
             $this.unwrap();   
        }
    });
};
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuu6cy2x/1/)

Obviously the name should be changed but the logic is sound.

Comment: You could just use `times` instead of setting it to a separate variable

Comment: True, I like to keep all my variables local; just a habit to make sure nothing is outside of the scope.

Comment: function arguments are local

Comment: Did you just whip that code up from scratch in a matter of seconds? I wish I was that smart...

Comment: Like I said it's a habit I have. @ShemSeger Yup

Comment: Formal variables ARE local.

Comment: `$.fn.unwrapTimes = function(n) {for (var a=this; n; n--) a=a.unwrap(); return a}` You're welcome.

Comment: unwrapping elements that share the same parents will ending unwrapping more than you bargained for.

Comment: @electricalbah please provide an example that will explain what you mean

Comment: @dbarnes Its simple
<div>
                <div>
                     <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                     <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                </div>
 </div>
unwrapping 1 time with the aim of removing the inner Div will end up unwrapping twice because of two a tags

Answer (score 10):

Use **[`parentsUntil`](https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/)**
the child of foo  (`.foo > *`)
(which would be an ancestor of the element).

Use [**`addBack`**](http://api.jquery.com/addback/) to include the element itself.

```
$('.foo a').parentsUntil('.foo > *').addBack().unwrap();
```

[**Fiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/42to6fu5/)

---

If you want a generic function that unwraps an object `n` times, this does it:

```
$.fn.unwrapN = function(n) {
  while(n--) $(this).unwrap();
  return $(this);
}
```

[**Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/f4a8a8tc/1/)

Comment: Nice one. Thanks for introducing a new method to me. This should be the accepted answer, IMO

Comment: Note this unwraps the immediate parent of the anchor element, and not the anchor element itself. ie you are left with `<li class="foo"><div><a>`

Answer (score 3):

Can use html()

```
$('.foo').html($('.foo a'));
```

That approach isn't scaleable for more than one though but can use `html(fn)` for multiple instances

```
$('.foo').html(function(){
   return $(this).find('a')
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pu7Lmxfr/)**

Comment: This doesn't work if you have more than one .foo list item. [See Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pu7Lmxfr/1/).

Comment: @RickHitchcock yeah   tricky one liner you got.. lots of dom manipulation...be curious to see perf tests on some of these...all the unwraps on many `.foo` not likely very performant

Comment: `.html()` destroys the elements. If, for example, you had click event listeners on `a` elements they get destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

Why overcomplicate it?

```
var $wrapper = $('li.foo'),
    $keep = $wrapper.find('a'),
    $result = $wrapper.empty().append($keep);

console.log($result[0].outerHTML);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k5mn0gnm/

Comment: This is good. But it kills all "uncles" of `li.foo a`, if there are any.

Comment: @SalmanA You mean siblings? What's an uncle in this context? :-)

Comment: Yes, siblings too. Uncles are siblings of parents.

Comment: @SalmanA Removing all parents until `.foo` is requirement , no ?

Answer (score 1):

For single `foo` elememt, try utilizing [`.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo) , [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty)

```
 $(".foo a").prependTo($(".foo").empty());
```

```js
$(".foo a").prependTo($(".foo").empty());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<li class="foo">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

---

For multiple `.foo` classes , try

```
$(".foo a").each(function() {
  $(this).prependTo($(this).parents(".foo").empty());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pu7Lmxfr/5/

Comment: Doesn't work with multiple list items: [See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pu7Lmxfr/3/).

Comment: @ShemSeger Only added an `.each()` http://jsfiddle.net/pu7Lmxfr/4/ . Perhaps include detail at OP that requirement is for `js` to be applied to "multiple list items" as well ?

Comment: Take another look at it, you've replaced all the links with a copy of the last link.

Comment: @ShemSeger http://jsfiddle.net/pu7Lmxfr/5/ ; updated post to include `js` from linked jsfiddle